# In Outlook, how can I delay the default "mark-as-read"?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

In outlook, can I create a behaviour such that a message will automatically marked as read only after a while in which is was in the reading pane?

It is really annoying that if I run through new mails it automatically marks them as read, but I wouln't like to have to go to each and mark it as read.

Is it possible in Outlook then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happily for you, it's an out of the box feature:

Open: ***File*** → ***Options*** → ***Advanced***

In the Outlook panes section, click ***Reading Pane***...

Then Mark the ***checkbox*** that defaultly marks messages as read when in reading pane, and set the delay time in seconds in the textbox. 
It this way, if you change the message selection before the time passes, it will not be marked as read. I guess it's what you were after.

***NOTE:*** In older versions of MS Outlook, opening the reading pane is a little different: 
***File*** → ***Options*** → ***Mail***
Under "Outlook Panes" → ***Reading Pane***

Good luck, 
Sit'n